# How to fix sklearn ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I got error while doing the task. ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 200 and input n_features is 201

```
[Number of features of the model must match the input][1] 
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O 
(e.g.pd.read_csv)
from sklearn import tree

import os
for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/kaggle/input'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))


from IPython.display import SVG
from graphviz import Source
from IPython.display import display

from IPython.display import HTML
style = "<style>svg{width:50% !important;height:50% !important;}</style>"
HTML(style)
DATA_DIR = '/kaggle/input/ds-masters-santander-comp1/'
train = pd.read_csv(DATA_DIR + 'santander_train.csv')
train.head()
X = train.drop(['target'], axis=1)
y = train.target
test = pd.read_csv(DATA_DIR + 'santander_test.csv')
test.head()
submission = clf.predict(test)
submission
sample_submission = pd.read_csv(DATA_DIR + 'santander_sample_submission.csv')
sample_submission.head()
sample_submission['Outcome'] = submission
sample_submission.to_csv('santander_sample_submission.csv', index=False)
sample_submission.head(10)`
```

[Number of features of the model must match the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuL3K.png)

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use the classifier to predict, you must train it on the training data. This can be done with `clf.fit(X, y)`.

Comment: thank you, fixed it, please help with another error

Comment: Your training and test data must have the same columns. For X you have dropped the target column, do the same for the test data before using it for prediction. This can be done with `test.drop(['target'], axis=1)`.